# println() with Printwriter object not writing to a file

Tags: java, printstream

Why is PrintWriter not writing to the file in the following code?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter input file name");
        String inputfile = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter output file name");
        String outputfile = in.nextLine();
        in.close();

        File f = new File(inputfile);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputfile);

        while( input.hasNextLine()){
            String s = input.nextLine(); ////// reading the file lines perfectlly
            output.print(s);    // but not writing 
        }    
        output.close();
        input.close();

    }
}
```

As mentioned in the code, the lines of the input files are being read but not written to the output file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java

Comment: thats exactly what I have done in the code above. I still cant find why it is not working.

Comment: This code seems ok, where did you check your output file(file path)? does your output file have write permission?

Comment: what are you feeding to `outputfile`? all fine with write permissions?

Comment: Its working. I wasn't giving .txt with the file name. SO I was just providing "file" in place of "file.txt". Strange that, scanner can read a file without extensions where as a printwriter can't write to a file without file extensions. Thanks.

Comment: @lynxx - `PrintWriter` can write files without extensions.  It is just that it won't automatically *add* an extension.  Why?  Because it has no idea what the correct extension should be!  (File extensions are an OS specific (i.e. non-portable) convention.  Java I/O pays them no special attention.)

Comment: @StephenC I tried doing it with the code provided in the question. With just the file name given such as "file", It made a new file as the name given by me but didn't write anything to it. When I added the the extension to the given file, It wrote in the file.

Comment: I agree with @StephenC. Just tested it on Ubuntu 18.04. You would still get a file without extension, which can be opened as normal text file.
It may be that you were not expecting it to be there.

Comment: I also tested on Ubuntu, and your code works exactly as expected.  Modulo a small bug that you have probably already spotted.  `print` != `println`  :-)

Comment: Most probably file is not in a place where you would expect it to be. IOException would be thrown otherwise.

Comment: You can simply check if the file exists after closing the `PrintWriter` using `File.exists` and `File.length`, you will notice it is correct. So you are probably not checking in the correct place.